# Change Instance Variable Based on Controller Name - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to make things DRY with the following partial:

```
<div class="controls <%= 'hide' if @videos.total_pages == 1 and !administrator? %>">
  <% if administrator? %>
    <%= link_to "New #{controller_name.capitalize.singularize}", new_video_path, {:style => "margin-right: 10px;"} %>
  <% end %>
  <%= will_paginate @videos, :class => "pagination", :inner_window => 1 %>
</div>
```

As you can see there is @videos appearing twice. Can I change these based solely on the controller name, similar to the link_to?

Comment: What about the path `new_video_path`. Isnt that fixed?

Comment: @Santosh I missed that but could just use `controller: "#{controller_name}", action: "new"` in it's place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while it may be just better not to go to crazy with the refactoring; the code below would solve the issue, if the technique would be needed:

```
<% @group = instance_variable_get("@#{controller_name}") %>

<div class="controls <%= 'hide' if @group.total_pages == 1 and !administrator? %>">
  <% if administrator? %>
    <%= link_to "New #{controller_name.capitalize.singularize}", controller: "#{controller_name}", action: "new", :style => "margin-right: 10px;" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= will_paginate @group, :class => "pagination", :inner_window => 1 %>
</div>
```

Now, the partial is usable across several views with similar functionality (ie photos)

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against this type of refactoring. There's a fine line between DRY-ness and readability. Too much abstraction can make your code difficult to understand and debug later, both for you and other people. So in my opinion, repeating an instance variable name a few times throughout a template is not a bad thing because you can tell at a glance what the code is supposed to be doing without thinking about the different contexts in which it will run.

Similarly, your `link_to` name is a bit *too* clever. I would also change it to simply say "New Video". Yeah, you may need a few identical partials (one for each controller) but their purpose and the way they execute will be a lot more clear.

Lastly, it looks like you're calling `hide` on video controls based on whether the user is an administrator. That's not very good design though since anyone who reads through the page's source can unhide the controls by changing the visibility/display values. I don't know what the rest of your code does though so maybe you're OK with that.

Comment: True, it may be best to have sanity over brevity in the situation.  I was still curious on how this would work. I have a possible solution I'll post below.  As for the "hide" there are admin and non-admin information there and currently it's possible that nothing is there except a big 'ol empty div that is taking up to much space.